# getting "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row" while selecting a row from Hive table

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, metadata

I have a table in hive in ORC format.Below is the create statement

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mydb.test(    
  transkey string,
  acckey string,
  name string,
  sex string,
  city string,
  gentime timestamp
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/data/gau/work/hive/test';
```

Now i want 2 extra fields to be added to this table so i altered the table and added 2 extra fields.

alter table Mydb.test add columns(location string, age int).

so after altering the table, i can see the field values of newly added columns in my old data as NULL as expected.
e.g if i fire this query 
select transkey,gentime,location,age from Mydb.test limit 5;

```
  +-----------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
|          transkey                 |         gentime        |      location   | age              |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
| asxxxxx                           | 2019-07-xx 04:24:19.0  | india           | 25               |
| rtyxxxxxxx                        | 2019-07-04 04:24:19.0  | afg             | 45               |
| uuinxxxxxx                        | 2019-xx-04 04:24:20.0  | test            | 67               |
| ghjkxxxxxxx                       | 2017-xx-06 09:01:14.0  | NULL            | NULL             |
| uuuixxxxxxx                       | 2017-xx-06 09:01:xxx   | NULL            | NULL             |
| xxxxyyxxx                         | 2017-xx-06 09:01:1xxxx | NULL            | NULL             |
```

But when i take a particular transkey from the old data( i can know whether the data is old or new by seeing the gentime for a record) and fire a query
like select age,location from Mydb.test where transkey='xxxxyyxxx'(as per the gentime xxxxyyxxx is the old data having both newly added fields as NULL) it errors out as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMa

pper.java:170)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.VectorExpressionWriterFactory$6.writeValue(VectorExpressionWriterFactory.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.VectorExpressionWriterFactory$VectorExpressionWriterBytes.writeValue(VectorExpressionWriterFactory.java:272)
```

Upon firing this above query,ideally i should get NULL values for those columns but instead i am getting this error.Please help.

P.S -All these queries work completely fine over new data having those two new columns

Comment: I think it has something to do with ORC format since in ORC both data and its schema are bundled together.The same thing works fine for a hive table in avro serde if I just update the .avsc file.

Comment: then its really strange why its not working for me

Comment: Actually this table in created in hive with ORC and we are populating it with a spark batch job and the format is hive.